# Media query not getting fired

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am new to web development and I am facing a hard time dealing with media queries.

I am creating a dance website but my following media queries in "media-query.css" are not getting fired.

```
@media screen and (max-width:1800px)  and (min-width: 399x) {
  .our-services ul li {
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 2rem;

  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .our-services ul li{
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding-left: 0rem;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
  }
}
```

Project link: https://github.com/abhinav700/DanceMasti.com

Comment: Please give us specific **HTML** code so that we can help you with your question, thank you. Or at least specify what file it is.

Comment: @AyushGupta You're repeating the OP's error with `399x` (instead of 399px). Whether it has `screen and` before it is irrelevant.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to do so. See the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

Answer (score 0):

Too lazy to go through all of those files so I'll list some common errors out here in case someone else finds this question and has a different cause:

- Maybe you haven't linked the file. Add `<link src="your-directory/media-query.css"></link>` to your html file.
- Your queries are being overridden by a file with a higher priority. Test this
  by leaving !important after your lines, i.e `width: 50px !important;`. Note that
  using important is considered bad code by some(I have no opinion on this,and
  have no idea if it's true).
- As posted by another user, your media query is a bit off, so you could be toeing
  the line and using exactly 400px. I doubt it though. The lower query should be
  taking precedence, so it still should look like a mobile view.
- Check to make sure that you are using the selectors correctly. Your selectors
  currently are looking for a `<li>` inside a `<ul>` inside any element with a
  class of `our-services`(someone correct me if I'm wrong). The way I like to
  check this is just to set a clause:

```
li{
  position: none;
}
```

and see if this element disappears. If it does and nothing else pops up... I got nothing.
If this answer helped, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score -1):

It says 399x instead of 401px. So it could be both a syntax issue and a overlap issue.

Comment: i am debugging this from 15 minutes and i don't know i miss things like that.can you give some tips

Comment: there is no such thing as a syntax arror like this. First it is nor an invalid syntax and secondly the rule is legitimate. It will apply at 400 pixels both rules.